# How to pass a pk of an object to a template form

Tags: python, django, forms, parameter-passing, primary-key

the scenario is as follows:
objects: race, racers, registration
I am trying to use a form to offer users the possibility to register to race.

models:

```
class registration(models.Model):
    STATUS = [
    ('Registered','Registered'),
    ('Confirmed','Confirmed'),
    ]
    race_id = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rrace')
    racer_id = models.ForeignKey(Racer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rracer')
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    medals = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="do you wish it?")
    registration_status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default='Registered', max_length=15)
```

forms:

```
 class RegisterRace(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = registration
        fields = ("race_id", "racer_id"")
```

url:

```
path('register-race/', views.race_register, name='race_register'),
```

views:

```
def race_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        c = request.POST.get('race') # this line is ONLY for debugging
        race = Race.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('race'))
        form = RegisterRace(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('races')
    else:
        form = RegisterRace()
    return render(request, 'race_registration.html', {'form': form, 'rc': race})
```

race_detail template contain the following link :

```
<form action="/register-race/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" name="race" value="{{event.pk}}"> # where event is the current race 
   <input type="submit"  value="REGISTRATION" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
</form>
```

race_registration.html template contain:

```
<form action="/register-race/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type = "hidden" name = "race_id" value="{{rc.pk}}"> # for debugging purpose here I have also tried with value="{{c}}"
        <input type = "hidden" name = "racer_id" value="{{request.user.pk}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">REGISTER MYSELF</button>
</form>
```

When I hit the Registration button the following error occurs:

> DoesNotExist at /register-race/ Race matching query does not exist.
>   Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/register-race/
>   Django Version:   3.0.2 Exception Type:   DoesNotExist Exception Value:
>   Race matching query does not exist. Exception
>   Location: C:\Users-----\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py
>   in get, line 415

Traceback:

```
..race\views.py in register-race
        race = Race.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('race')) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
c           None
request     <WSGIRequest: POST '/register-race/'>
```

Regardless of the above in the template race_registration.html I have put:

```
Register to race {{race.race_type}} which have the id {{race.pk}}
```

and the render is as expected -- Register to race INDIANAPOLIS 2020 which have the id 19

Therefore, I do not understand where is the mistake and why the form cannot receive the right value ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you make it really complicated for nothing. Why using forms?

Why not doing this:

**urls.py**

```py
path('register-race/<race_id>', views.race_register, name='race_register'),
```

**race_detail_template**

```html
<a href="{%url 'race_register' race_id=event.pk %}">Register me on this race</a>
```

**view**

```py
def race_register(request, race_id):
    try:
        race = Race.objects.get(pk=race_id)
        race.rracers.add(your_racer_object)
    except Race.DoesNotExist:
        #deal with the problem
    return redirect(wereveryouwant)
```

Comment: Thank you, Tartempion34! But how does this method save the request into the db? I am using forms to save the request into the database ...

Comment: this line:
        race.users.add(request.user)
Tell that you want to save in the database a new relation ship between this race and this user (I put user because I didn't see your models but it can be racers for example)

Comment: My goal is to save into registration model - just updated the post with this model

Comment: Ok it make no sense you're form doesn't match at all with your model. Can you explain what is the objective? You want a user to click on a race and to have a form for this specific race where he can chose for a medal or not?

Comment: I have races and racers. I want a racer to access a specific race (race_detail template) and to click on Register. Based on this action I need to save in Registration model a new entry with race_id, racer_id, date, medal and status. Because not all Racers will qualify to take part in the race the status is initially Registered and it will became Confirmed later. The boolean field - medal is to track if after the race the racer desire a medal or not. I hope this clarifies better.

Comment: I edited my answer. But for more accurate answer it can be great to have all the models invlved (which means race model racer model and registration model. And to know the racer is the user connected?